# Magento CE 1.9 Script for setting stock

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, script, stock-status, manage-stock

I need a script that will check all magento products and set them to instock if the qty is greater than 0.

The plan is to run this as a scheduled cronjob so that it will be checking for any products that have their stock value incorrectly set.

My code is rather crude so far but here is what i have come up with:

```
<?php PHP_SAPI == 'cli' or die;
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$stock_item = $product->getStockItem();

     if ($stock_item->getQty() < 0){
        $stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
        $stockItem->save();
        $product->save();
     }
?>
```

Unfortunately when i run this nothing changes in the backend and no products are set to instock as they should.

Perhaps somebody could point to where i'm going wrong or a better solution?

Comment: if ($stock_item->getQty() > 0)  and check the manage_stock to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try this way. Hope it works.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->load($product_id);
$stockItem =    Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product->getId());
        if($stockItem->getQty() > 0) {
           $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
           $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);                  
        } else {
           $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 0);
                        }
        $stockItem->save();
```

Comment: Thanks @albeis i've tried your code above but for some reason i'm getting integrity contstraint errors now. `[06-Aug-2018 16:54:02 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`willowhill_ma156`.`mgax_cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_MGAX_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_MGAX_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `mgax_catalog_product_entit) in /home/willowhill/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228`.